# Hadoop with zookeeper

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper

I am new to apache zookeeper and I read from an article that

```
Zookeeper manages the entire workflow of starting and stopping various nodes in the Hadoop’s cluster.
```

If it so, can anyone tell me how..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732834/why-we-need-zookeeper-with-hadoop

Answer (score 2):

In HADOOP when u create multiple node cluster ,for co-ordination between data nodes and name node zookeeper is used.

It regularly updates the status of datanodes.

Comment: ...I have one doubt...In hadoop when I make multiple cluster...for instance say 20...whether I must have zookeeper servers in all nodes or not...@Sandeep Das