# Apache zookeeper concept

Tags: apache, hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I am new to zookeeper and after weeks of reading documentations and I got confused with its concepts.
Acoording to me,

> Zookeper provides set of apis so that we can make use of it to
>   co-ordinate the distributed application.

Anyone correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> Zookeeper is about distributed computing

Good tutorials
1)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RfBHqDWa60
2)[Why do we need ZooKeeper in the Hadoop stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732834/why-we-need-zookeeper-with-hadoop)
3)https://www.igvita.com/2010/04/30/distributed-coordination-with-zookeeper/
4)http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.2/index.html

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right ..

Zookeeper is also used for configuration management in distributed applications .

Go through hadoop book (2009-Book-Hadoop the Definitive Guide )to know more about zookeeper .